# Does cats mapN run all the futures in parallel?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

As mentioned in the [jump-start guide](https://typelevel.org/cats/jump_start_guide.html), mapN will run all the futures in parallel, so I created the below simple Scala program, but a sample run shows **diff** to be **9187 ms** and **diffN** to be **9106 ms**. *So it looks like that the mapN is also running the futures sequentially, isn't it?* Please let me know if I am missing something?

```
package example

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.Duration
import scala.util.Failure
import scala.util.Success
import java.time.ZoneOffset

import cats.instances.future._
import cats.syntax.apply._

object FutureEx extends App {

  val before = LocalDateTime.now()

  val sum = for {
    a <- getA
    b <- getB
    c <- getC
  } yield (a + b + c)

  sum onComplete {
    case Failure(ex) => println(s"Error: ${ex.getMessage()}")

    case Success(value) =>
      val after = LocalDateTime.now()
      println(s"before: $before")
      println(s"after: $after")

      val diff = getDiff(before, after)
      println(s"diff: $diff")
      println(s"sum: $value")
  }

  // let the above finish
  Thread.sleep(20000)
  
  val beforeN = LocalDateTime.now()
  val usingMapN = (getA, getB, getC).mapN(add)

  usingMapN onComplete {
    case Failure(ex) => println(s"Error: ${ex.getMessage()}")

    case Success(value) =>
      val afterN = LocalDateTime.now()
      println(s"beforeN: $beforeN")
      println(s"afterN: $afterN")

      val diff = getDiff(beforeN, afterN)
      println(s"diffN: $diff")
      println(s"sum: $value")
  }

  def getA: Future[Int] = {
    println("inside A")
    Thread.sleep(3000)
    Future.successful(2)
  }

  def getB: Future[Int] = {
    println("inside B")
    Thread.sleep(3000)
    Future.successful(3)
  }

  def getC: Future[Int] = {
    println("inside C")
    Thread.sleep(3000)
    Future.successful(4)
  }

  def add(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) = a + b + c

  def getDiff(before: LocalDateTime, after: LocalDateTime): Long = {
    Duration.between(before.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC), after.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)).toMillis()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have `sleep` outside `Future` it should be like:

```
def getA: Future[Int] = Future {
    println("inside A")
    Thread.sleep(3000)
    2
  }
```

So you start async `Future` with `apply` - `Future.successful` on the other hand returns pure value, meaning you execute `sleep` in same thread.

Answer (score 0):

The time is going before `mapN` is ever called.

```
(getA, getB, getC).mapN(add)
```

This expression is creating a tuple (sequentially) and then calling `mapN` on it. So it is calling `getA` then `getB` then `getC` and since each of them has a 3 second delay, it takes 9 seconds.